# Sound feature attributeError: 'rmse'

Tags: python, audio, feature-extraction, librosa

In using librosa.feature.rmse for sound feature extraction, I have the following:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np 

wav_file = "C://TEM//tem//CantinaBand3.wav"
y, sr = librosa.load(wav_file)

chroma_stft = librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=y, sr=sr)

rmse=librosa.feature.rmse(y=y)[0]

print rmse
```

It gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rmse'
```

What's the right way to get it?

Sample file: [https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/CantinaBand3.wav](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/%7Ei101/SoundFiles/CantinaBand3.wav)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am guessing you are running one of the latest `librosa`. If you check the [changelog](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/17a5852ca1d052cb6f54ca9849c8fd97edf6c939/docs/changelog.rst) for the `0.7`, you will notice that `rmse` was dropped in favour of `rms`. Simply run:

```
rmse=librosa.feature.rms(y=y)[0]
```

and you should be fine.